# TikZ data visualization - multiple plots in the same axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I am trying to declare a new data format with the TikZ data visualization library for a custom data file format. The data files have a header section with `Field name = Value` followed by a blank line and subsequently  the data in four columns.

My declared data format `mydata` seems to work, but I cannot figure out how to plot `value 1` and `value 2` as a function of `time` without reading the same data file twice. Any help appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{"datafile.txt"}
Header field 1 = Header value 1
Header field 2 = Header value 2
Header field 3 = ...
Header field N = Header value N

Data
0   -6.283  0.000   1.000
1   -5.027  0.951   0.309
2   -3.770  0.588   -0.809
3   -2.513  -0.588  -0.809
4   -1.257  -0.951  0.309
5   0.000   0.000   1.000
6   1.257   0.951   0.309
7   2.513   0.588   -0.809
8   3.770   -0.588  -0.809
9   5.027   -0.951  0.309
10  6.283   0.000   1.000
\end{filecontents*}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\def\ignoreheader{%
    \catcode`A=14\relax\catcode`B=14\relax\catcode`C=14\relax\catcode`D=14\relax
    \catcode`E=14\relax\catcode`F=14\relax\catcode`G=14\relax\catcode`H=14\relax
    \catcode`I=14\relax\catcode`J=14\relax\catcode`K=14\relax\catcode`L=14\relax
    \catcode`M=14\relax\catcode`N=14\relax\catcode`O=14\relax\catcode`P=14\relax
    \catcode`Q=14\relax\catcode`R=14\relax\catcode`S=14\relax\catcode`T=14\relax
    \catcode`U=14\relax\catcode`V=14\relax\catcode`X=14\relax\catcode`Y=14\relax
    \catcode`Z=14\relax
}%
\pgfdeclaredataformat{mydata}%
    {\ignoreheader}{}{#1    #2  #3  #4}
    {%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/index}{#1}%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/time}{#2}%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/value 1}{#3}%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/value 2}{#4}%
        \pgfdatapoint
    }{}{}%
\pgfdeclaredataformat{value 1}%
    {\ignoreheader}{}{#1    #2  #3  #4}
    {%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/time}{#2}%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/value}{#3}%
        \pgfdatapoint
    }{}{}%
\pgfdeclaredataformat{value 2}%
    {\ignoreheader}{}{#1    #2  #3  #4}
    {%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/time}{#2}%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/value}{#4}%
        \pgfdatapoint
    }{}{}%

\begin{document}

This works, but the is read twice\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        school book axes,
        visualize as line/.list={value 1,value 2},
        x axis={length=10cm,attribute=time},
        y axis={length=3cm,attribute=value},
        style sheet=strong colors,
        ]
        data[set=value 1,read from file={"datafile.txt"},format=value 1]
        data[set=value 2,read from file={"datafile.txt"},format=value 2];
\end{tikzpicture}

Plotting each of values 1 and 2 in a separate visualization works:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        school book axes,
        visualize as line,
        x axis={length=10cm,attribute=time},
        y axis={length=3cm,attribute=value 1},
        style sheet=strong colors,
        ]
        data[read from file={"datafile.txt"},format=mydata];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        school book axes,
        visualize as line,
        x axis={length=10cm,attribute=time},
        y axis={length=3cm,attribute=value 2},
        style sheet=strong colors,
        ]
        data[read from file={"datafile.txt"},format=mydata];
\end{tikzpicture}


This does not work:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        school book axes,
        visualize as line/.list={value 1,value 2},
        x axis={length=10cm,attribute=time},
        y axis={length=3cm,attribute/.list={value 1,value 2}},
        style sheet=strong colors,
        ]
        data[read from file={"datafile.txt"},format=mydata];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create two `\pgfdatapoint`s per line in the table, with the same variable names for `x` and `y`, but with a different `set` number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{"datafile.txt"}
Header field 1 = Header value 1
Header field 2 = Header value 2
Header field 3 = ...
Header field N = Header value N

Data
0   -6.283  0.000   1.000
1   -5.027  0.951   0.309
2   -3.770  0.588   -0.809
3   -2.513  -0.588  -0.809
4   -1.257  -0.951  0.309
5   0.000   0.000   1.000
6   1.257   0.951   0.309
7   2.513   0.588   -0.809
8   3.770   -0.588  -0.809
9   5.027   -0.951  0.309
10  6.283   0.000   1.000
\end{filecontents*}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\def\ignoreheader{%
    \catcode`A=14\relax\catcode`B=14\relax\catcode`C=14\relax\catcode`D=14\relax
    \catcode`E=14\relax\catcode`F=14\relax\catcode`G=14\relax\catcode`H=14\relax
    \catcode`I=14\relax\catcode`J=14\relax\catcode`K=14\relax\catcode`L=14\relax
    \catcode`M=14\relax\catcode`N=14\relax\catcode`O=14\relax\catcode`P=14\relax
    \catcode`Q=14\relax\catcode`R=14\relax\catcode`S=14\relax\catcode`T=14\relax
    \catcode`U=14\relax\catcode`V=14\relax\catcode`X=14\relax\catcode`Y=14\relax
    \catcode`Z=14\relax
}%
\pgfdeclaredataformat{mydata}%
    {\ignoreheader}{}{#1    #2  #3    #4}
    {%
    \pgfkeys{/data point/.cd,index=#1, x=#2, y=#3, set=1} \pgfdatapoint
    \pgfkeys{/data point/.cd,index=#1, x=#2, y=#4, set=2} \pgfdatapoint
    }{}{}%

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        school book axes,
        visualize as line/.list={1,2},
        style sheet=strong colors
        ]
        data [read from file="datafile.txt", format=mydata];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```